# ng-file-upload not hitting correct endpoint

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEANJS. I am using `ng-file-upload` in my client to upload a file. The problem is that in the `url` I have defined for the upload, there are no parameters in it but when hitting the endpoint, it invokes the function where it thinks there is a parameter in it. This `upload` is being done on the creation of a new `activity` *(`activities` are the same structure as the default `articles`)*

**Controller:**

```
function save(isValid) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'api/activities/gpxData', // no optional parameter ':activityId'
        data: {
            file: $scope.gpxData
        }
        }).then(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        }, function(resp) {
            console.log(resp)
        }, function(evt) {

        }
    });     
}
```

These are all my `route`'s defined:

```
app.route('/api/activities').all(activitiesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(activities.list)
    .post(activities.create);

app.route('/api/:userId/activities').all(activitiesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(activities.usersActivities)
    .post(activities.create);

app.route('/api/activities/:activityId').all(activitiesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(activities.read)
    .put(activities.update)
    .delete(activities.delete);

app.route('/api/:userId/activities/:activityId').all(activitiesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(activities.read)
    .put(activities.update)
    .delete(activities.delete);

app.route('/api/activities/gpxData').all(activitiesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .post(activities.uploadGpx);

// Finish by binding the Activity middleware
app.param('activityId', activities.activityByID);
```

Even though there is no optional parameter *(`activityId`)* being passed in the `url`, the function `activities.activityByID` is invoked which is this:

```
exports.activityByID = function (req, res, next, id) {
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Activity is invalid'
        });
    }
};
```

Also, there is an `id` being passed in *(which is the `id` of the `activity` being created)* but I do not know where from and it is not a valid `id` as it has not yet been entered into mongo.

Comment: It is probably caused by routing ordering. Because /api/activities/gpxData fits to pattern /api/activities/:activityId . Move app.route('/api/activities/gpxData') as first routing rule. And then try to run. And check if ng-file-upload is using PUT or POST

Comment: This seems to have fixed it, thank you! Post as an answer and I will accept. However, why does express care about the ordering of its routes like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by routing ordering in your express code. because /api/activities/gpxData fits to pattern /api/activities/:activityId.
The routing stops on the first matching rule and execute. This is standard implementation of routing in various technologies.

Move

```
app.route('/api/activities/gpxData').all(activitiesPolicy.isAllowed)
   .post(activities.uploadGpx);
```

before

```
app.route('/api/activities/:activityId').all(activitiesPolicy.isAllowed)
   .get(activities.read)
   .put(activities.update)
   .delete(activities.delete);
```

and then try to run.